# Keep tab active class across different pages

Tags: jquery, class, tabs

I can't find an answer that doesn't seem to refer to tabs within *one* page rather than across *multiple* pages, so...here we are!

I have this block of code appearing in several pages that represents a tabbed effect:

```
<ul id="teams-tabs" class="content-tabs-main group">
    <li><a href="http://localhost/first-team/">1st team<span></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/reserves/">Reserves<span></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

When the user is visiting, for example, the **first team** home page, or a sub page of the first team, the 1st team tab is given an active state using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var current_url = window.location.href;     
    $(".content-tabs-main li a").each(function(){
        var main_tab_href = $(this).attr("href");
        if (current_url.indexOf(main_tab_href) > -1) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("active-main-tab");
        }
    });
});
```

This all works perfectly well, however as the html is refreshed every time the page is reloaded or a sub-page of **first team** is visited, the active state flicks off and on again each time, which is kind of annoying.

Does anyone have a solution whereby the active state is retained without first switching back to its default "off" state if the page requires it?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to simply compare the current URL of the page to the `href` of the `<a>` elements; if they're the same then that's the page you're on:

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    // note that we're using the 'href' property, not the attribute, to
    // get an absolute URL rather than a, potentially, relative URL (this
    // is why we're using filter() rather than an attribute selector)
    return this.href === window.location;
}).closest('li').addClass('active-main-tab');
```

Or, if you have HTML similar to:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/first-team">First Team</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#captain">Captain</a></li>
            <li><a href="#striker">Striker</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And, after following the link to `#captain`, you want both the `#captain` *and* `first-team` `<li>` elements to have the active state:

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    return this.hash === window.location.hash || this.href === window.location;
}).closest('li').addClass('active-main-tab');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Just to clarify, is the above code intended to simply add the active state to the relevant tab, but in a way that leaves less margin for error with the href and url comparison? If so, I appreciate that and will use it, but I don't see anything that will carry the active tab state across to the next page, or a refresh of the same page...

Comment: There's nothing to explicitly run the code on any given occasion, but if you run it on `$(document).ready(function(){ /* in here */ });` then it'll run on page-load (and will therefore be run on the next page). I don't know what you mean, by 'leaves less margin for error with the href and url...' (I understand the words, but not your intent).

Comment: What I would like to do is check the href against the current url and add an active tab state (as you have done here), but then if the current page is refreshed, for example, the active state should remain in place rather than first resetting the html to its default state of **no class**, causing the effect to flick off and on again. 

If your code does do this and I am just being ignorant, would you mind briefly explaining how it works? Otherwise, I hope this has clarified what I was getting at better!

Comment: Ah, no; there'll always be a (potential for a) 'flash' as JavaScript executes and runs; there's no way for JavaScript to influence the behaviour of another page; if you're not able to tolerate that hopefully (but not guaranteed) minor update delay, then you may need to assign the active states of a given page server-side.

Comment: Excellent! We're on the same page now :) So would that require PHP or AJAX? If so, do you have any suggestions to point me in the right direction? I am fairly comfortable with PHP, but not so much AJAX. 

Also, in your opinion, would the update delay be frustrating to the user, or am I just being overly picky?

Comment: I'd imagine it would be primarily, and probably purely, PHP. It's been a while since I last used it, but I'd suggest having PHP assessing the URL of the requested page, and inserting a class-name into the relevant elements opening tags. Beyond that I'm not able to help, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you for helping as far as you could. I'll look into a PHP solution and post an answer if I find one.